# Merge files with starting pattern in R

Tags: r, loops, merge, rstudio

I have a directory with many las-files. 
It looks like this the picture bellow, but with hunderds of files.

[image]

I would like to merge all the files starting with the same name (till the "_" character)

I have managed to develop a script which merges all the files with the same pattern

```
masterlist =list.files("//directory/",pattern="^name1")
listfiles <- paste("//directory/",masterlist, sep="")

#concatenate files into one file
con_files = c(listfiles)

lasread <- readLAS(con_files)
lasmerge <- rbind(lasread)
writeLAS(lasmerge, "//write/directory/name1.las")
```

However, In this script I have hard coded "name1". 
I would like this to be dynamic based on the filenames.

So it should be some kind of loop based on a list, but I don't know how the create a loop with a dynamic pattern.

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: so all the `name1` files would merge separately, `name2` separately and so on?

Comment: Yes indeed that is what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just creaste a list of patterns and run the code for every pattern.
Like so

```
path <- "."
write_path <- "."
patterns <- list.files(path, pattern = ".*\\.las")
patterns <- strsplit(patterns, "_")
patterns <- unique(sapply(patterns, function(x) x[1]))

for(p in patterns) {
    masterlist <- list.files(path, pattern = paste0("^", p))
    listfiles <- paste(path, masterlist, sep = "")

    #concatenate files into one file
    con_files = c(listfiles)

    lasread <- readLAS(con_files)
    lasmerge <- rbind(lasread)
    writeLAS(lasmerge, file.path(write_path, paste0(p, ".las")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code which is shared works for one type of "name", we can split the `masterlist` based on similar pattern in names and apply the same function to all the groups

```
masterlist <- list.files("//directory/",pattern="\\.las$")
name_pat <- sub("[_ ].*", "", masterlist)

Map(function(x, y) {
    lasread <- readLAS(x)
    lasmerge <- rbind(lasread)
    writeLAS(lasmerge, paste0("//write/directory/", y, ".las"))
}, split(masterlist, name_pat), unique(name_pat))
```

Comment: The filename "name1" was just an example obviously. But the filenmaes are more like: name, example, test, etc. I have changed the image.

Comment: @Stefan You'll need a small change I think. `masterlist <- list.files("//directory/",pattern="\\.las$")`